# Input a letter to 'int'

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Code:

```
int a;
cin>>a;
cout<<a<<endl;
```

Then I use `g++ test.cpp`, and run it. Then I input a letter 'b' to the variable a. The output is 0.

But, When I test the Other code:

```
cout<<int('b')<<endl;   // output: 98
```

Why? What is the different?

Comment: Have removed the `C` tag for you. Please note that `C` and `C++` are distinct languages.

Comment: The first bit of code doesn't say to convert a character to an integer. The second does. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cin` is an object, an instance of a `std::istream`. `std::istream` has overloaded the `>>` to support [a variety of types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). One of those types is `&int`. When there is a `std::istream` on the left of `>>` and an integer reference on the right, the method `istream& operator>> (int& val)` is called. The conceptual implementation of that method is as follows.

1. Store 0 in an accumulator
2. Read a character of the input
3. If the character is 0-9, add its decimal value to the accumulator
4. If not, return the value of the accumulator
5. Return to step 2

When you provide 'b' as input to `istream& operator>> (int& val)`, it immediately stores the "accumulated" 0 in your `int` variable. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (const int argc, const char * const argv[]) {
    int b = 100;

    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
100
b
0
```

As for the cast, when you cast the value `'b'` to an integer, you already have a byte in memory with the value 98, which you then print as an integer. When you use `>>` the resulting value in memory is 0, which you then print as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The input operation that you are trying to do is failing.  Since `a` is an `int` `cin` expects an `int`.  since it gets a `char` it fails.  You can test this by changing you code to:

```
int a;
cin>>a;
if(!cin)
    cout << "input failed";
else
    cout<<a<<endl;
```

Input:

```
a
```

Output:

```
input failed
```

See this [live example](http://ideone.com/lUA50L)

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect error handling for `cin >> &int`. 0 is a valid integer input, and evaluates as `false`, which you wold declare as "input failed".

Answer (score 0):

When you are using 'b' to cin a integer value, your program think you are input a invalid number, so it does't assign value by int('b'). still using initial value of a

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this what you're finding:

```
char a;

cin >> a;
cout << a << endl;
```

try to change `int` to `char`,
when you enter `3`, it'll output `3`;
when you enter `b`, it'll output `b`;

if you want to output ascii, you can make cout like:

```
cout << (int) a << endl;
```

then you'll get `98` when you enter `b`

Answer (score 0):

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is
> expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set. (until C++11)
>
> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If
> extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in
> value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min()
> is written and failbit flag is set. (since C++11)

from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt